# python 3.6, for input() - achieve time out and skip to next line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Newbie to python.

I looked around the web and found raw_input() had some workaround to achieve timeout. But in 3.6 there is no raw_input()

```
 name1 = str(input("please enter name of preferred student 1: "))
 name2 = str(input("please enter name of preferred student 2: "))
```

I want user to enter input for first line in 5 secs, if he dint enter any input i want my code to skip for second line of code.

Comment: Am newbie i dint understand much in that, not sure of duplicate.

Comment: Am trying timeout with input() function, not print("")

Comment: The duplicate question explains *exactly* what you're trying to do, the first answer is most applicable. Create a signal and a handler that raises an Exception; wrap timed code in try-except to catch aforementioned exception.